# SQL Server count of ID new orders and orders in process

Tags: sql-server

I have a count of ID of customers that have ordered from the company on a date.

I would like to count the ID of the customers that had however orders still in progress on that date and add them together

Table is called `Order`

```
ID
Date
Status.. this has option of outstanding or complete
```

Please help

Comment: Without any context I will suggest that your goal may be impossible. You give little context (to match the DDL) so we don't know that the column "date" reflects. Is it set to the current date when the row is created? For a given date (e.g., May 11, 2018) how do you know that an order is "new" or that an order is "in process"? You might be able to find new orders, but it seems you don't have sufficient information to find incomplete ones. Perhaps your context is only based on the current date and current status - but your description is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM ORDER WHERE DATE = 'YOUR DATE' AND STATUS = 'OUTSTANDING'
```

This will count how many IDS have outstanding orders on a chosen date but if you wish to get the SUM of IDs then use

```
SELECT SUM(ID) FROM ORDER WHERE DATE = 'YOUR DATE' AND STATUS = 'OUTSTANDING'
```

**ALSO**
If a ID comes up with more than 1 standing order etc for the same date just use `DISTINCT`with the above queries

Comment: In what context would a *sum* of ID values ever be useful?

Comment: @JeroenMostert No context at all, but I do believe the wording of OP's answer involved "count the ID" which the definition of means "determine the total number of (a collection of items)." which would therefore suggest SUM. I know it's useless but with information provided from OP I can only assume so i applied solutions to what both meanings they may of meant.